# Can I use wider tires on my truck?

Tags: ford, tires, f-150

I have a 2014 F150 that came with P235/75R17 tires. I need new tires and the mechanic at the garage said I could could also get P265/70R17 tires. He said for my model there would be no issues as they can come with both.

Yet the sticker the driver's side door rather explicitly said P235 for both the front and back wheels.

Is the mechanic right? I would like to buy P265 tires, all things being equal, so long as they wouldn't impact the performance of my truck.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Are you planning on changing all 4 and your spare? Is this a 4x4  F150?

Comment: All 4 tires yes. And yes it's a 4x4.

Answer (score 3):

Can they be installed on your vehicle? Absolutely. I think without too much of an impact. The 265 tires themselves will be about an inch wider (3cm = ~1.19"). That's not a huge amount. Considering it will be split between the two sides of the tire, it means they'll only be about a 1/2" wider on each side. This shouldn't cause any issues with turning in the front or sticking out past the fenders. You'd have to check for sure that the rolling distance (measured in rotations per mile or RPMs ... yah, kinda stupid, eh?) is the same or near the same, but considering that these are 70 aspect ratio where the old ones are 75, I'm going to bet they are pretty much the same.

As for performance, when you have a wider tire, you can expect that they will be harder for the truck to turn due to greater rolling resistance (more material = more resistance). This isn't going to be a huge amount, but it'll still be there.

Anyway, over all, there really shouldn't be any issues.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! I would upvote but my account is too new.

Comment: @dedles - You can upvote from jump street. You get up to 40 votes per day.